# OP-Amp active filter analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

Could you help me derive this transfer function for this OP-Amp circuit, I keep trying different methods and get no where close!

[image]

Comment: The voltage at the V+ op amp input is Vo. Use nodal analysis at the z1, z2, z3 node, and the V+ node.

Comment: You'd better showing your work so everyone can see where you go astray.

Comment: Nodal analysis to work out the voltage at those nodes? Isn't the voltage at z2=Vo, z3=Vo, V+=Vo? What is there to work out at those?

Comment: [It's in here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjtk5Pr0_rZAhUIvBQKHfkHANYQFggvMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com.cn%2Fcn%2Flit%2Fan%2Fsloa024b%2Fsloa024b.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2nR34LyyJUYF4xP35dfM5H)

Answer (score 1):

I just worked this out. Math becomes a little easier if you use admittance instead of impedance. I hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path is to apply [superposition](https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/papers/superpos.pdf) to this op-amp. Split the circuit for \$V_{in}=0\$ and \$V_{out}=0\$. Determine \$\epsilon\$ in both cases and the sum of the determined values is 0 V considering an infinite gain. The first drawing shows the circuit for \$V_{out}=0\$:

[image]

The voltage at the non-inverting pin is simply:

\$\epsilon_1=V_{in}\frac{Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}\frac{Z_4}{Z_4+Z_2+\frac{Z_1Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}}\$

Now set \$V_{in}=0\$:

You have: \$\epsilon_2=V_{out}\frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_3}\frac{Z_4}{Z_4+Z_2+\frac{Z_1Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}}-V_{out}\$

[image]

Now solve for \$V_{out}\$ when \$\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=0\$. You have \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{Z_3Z_4}{Z_1Z_3+Z_2Z_3+Z_3Z_4+Z_1Z_2}\$

If \$Z_3\$ and \$Z_4\$ are 10-nF capacitors, then Mathcad plots the dynamic response of this filter:

[image]

If you now try to develop the expression in which \$Z_3\$ and \$Z_4\$ are capacitance, you'll end up in an ugly result which will need further energy to factor it into a second-order polynomial form. If you apply the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371), you'll be there straight away.